# CSS text padding difference Firefox vs Chrome and others

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, height

if someone could help on the following would appreciate this as I spent the whole evening without result on this issue.

I have a site where I want to modify tags appearance after every article.
The problem is that firefox (version 14.0.1) provides smaller height for the text (total <a> height is 15px icnluding 1px bottom padding), while chrome and rest browsers give height 19px. So the difference is 4px. Because of this - the "tag hole" is displayed at different levels. A little bit lower than vertical middle for FF and upper than middle for rest browsers.

I made a picture to get the problem easier:
[image]

I have general css reset, so that different browsers behave similar. But it looks like not everything is included there.
Has anyone an idea what could cause this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block;` to your `.tags li a`

This won't affect the well-behaving browsers, but will fix FF

Comment: Super, that really did the trick. And now `line-height` is working, so I can get the needed height. Thanks.