# Firefox rendering differently than Safari/Chrome

Tags: html, css, firefox, safari

I've spent a few good hours debugging myself, and a few good hours researching but nothing seems to be solving my problem. I have a caption in my header that is supposed to be cut-off at the bottom, which looks fine in Safari and Chrome, but in Firefox it is positioned much higher:

> > **First window:** Firefox
> >
> > **Second window:** Safari (chrome renders the same)

[image]

I spent about an hour and a half changing everything around in my CSS thinking it had to do with other elements around it, but made no progress. Finally I decided to make an extremely simplified version to see what the problem is:

> > **First window:** Firefox
> >
> > **Second window:** Safari (chrome renders the same)

[image]

Same exact thing. I have a CSS reset applied so that is not the problem. I've tried setting the `line-height`, but that didn't fix it. I've tried every value for the CSS display property. Nothing is fixing this.

HTML/CSS for test example above:

```
<div class="test">
    <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```

---

```
.test {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 185px;
    line-height: 185px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.test h1 {
    font-size: 12em;
}
```

- My website can be viewed at [samrapdev.com](http://www.samrapdev.com).
- Quick link to [CSS stylesheet](http://samrapdev.com/CSS/main.css)
- In short, I need to figure out how to get both browsers to display the text at exactly the same height

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713163/css-text-padding-difference-firefox-vs-chrome-and-others

Comment: Your website uses a responsive layout. On changing the size of the browser, the baseline of the text changes. Did you notice that?

Comment: I had already seen that question @Sico did not solve my problem

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to change on resize when it gets smaller. Right now the problem has nothing to do with resizing though @AlexanderKimaru

Comment: Just realised the fonts look slightly larger on FF. Weird!

Comment: Got almost the same results when you specify a font-family. Tested on Mozilla and Firefox using font-family: "Open Sans"

Comment: Just tried it. There's still a good 7 or 8 pixel difference @AlexanderKimaru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and specify a font-family in your stylesheet though it's not pixel perfect[image]

Comment: exact! OP needs to use a web font, because on mac the title will be displayed using helvetica, on windows it appears as arial. fonts are similar but not identical

Comment: There is one, first line in main.css

Comment: Then why does Firefox on mac look different than Safari/Chrome also on mac? @Wesabi

Comment: i have no idea, i don't have a mac, but you certainly need the same font for all systems

Comment: Thank you both for all your help. I can not believe the solution was this simple! Thanks! @AlexanderKimaru

Comment: And @Wesabi I can only tag one at once

Answer (score 1):

```
#header .youAreHere h1
{
    ...
    line-height:1;
}
```

line-height must be set on h1, unless you have something like

```
* {line-height:inherit;}
```

[image: proof]

Comment: I changed the line-height to 137 px like your example but it is still rendering higher in firefox

Comment: read also the answer from Alexander Kimaru, you may need to use the same web font for all systems ( http://www.google.com/fonts ) instead of "helvetica, arial, sans-serif"

Comment: That solved it! Arial needs to take priority. WOW what a simple fix

Comment: your solution isn't rock solid yet, again as Alexander Kimaru suggested, you have to use the same font for all systems, like `h1{font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;}` adding `@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);`
 at the top of your css file

Comment: Oh I know I was referring to Alexander's answer solving it. I put Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif as my font family. It seems Firefox doesn't render Helvetica even on Mac

Comment: Use font squirrel to download the font to your computer then you can force using font-face

Comment: Yea I'll do that. Thanks for the help I've been pounding away at the keyboard since 11:30am and its 5:00 pm here right now. Can't believe I made such a noob mistake

Answer (score 1):

Even if you take a webfont and define the line-height of your element you can have variations due to the line-heights of the other elements.

What works for me is to define the line-height of the body on the top of using a webfont.

Also do not forget to reset margins and paddings for all elements you're using. A good trick is to use a reset.css before your actual style sheet (you can find some at http://www.cssreset.com/)

```
body{
    line-height: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I actually already use that exact reset stylesheet in my websites!

Comment: (The eric meyer's one)