# Padding Issues in Chrome vs Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, padding

Having issues with aligning my button text across browsers.  I've combed similar questions and have tried the suggestions but to no avail (display: inline-block for my hyperlinks, line-height: 1).  There is too much headroom in firefox with my buttons (see homepage slider) and it looks just fine though in Chrome. Site is: jdd.meteor.com

*I was told this question was "off topic" when I tried to ask before.  Please let me know what I can do to keep this question active if it is not on topic, whatever that means, so I can make changes.

Thanks!!

Screen captures (Chrome then Firefox):

[image: Chrome]
[image: FireFox]

```
#middle-section #slider .item .content hgroup a.call-to-action {
background: #820024;
color: white;
padding: 20px 30px;
letter-spacing: 0px;
font-size: 1.2em;
}
a {
color: #00aab5;
display: inline-block;
line-height: 1;
}
```

Comment: You need to post your code in your question. The HTML and CSS.

Comment: Set line-height to 58px on the button and remove the top and bottom padding. Now they should behave equally.

Comment: reset padding and margin and try to adjust the line-height accordingly will help you to fix the issue!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS text padding difference Firefox vs Chrome and others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713163/css-text-padding-difference-firefox-vs-chrome-and-others)

Comment: The reason that the last time you asked this question it was declared off topic is because you haven't provided an easy way to recreate the problem. Make it easy to recreate! The line-height of different typefaces vary, [use this as a starting point](http://jsbin.com/parese/4/edit) and get the `@font-face` working to provide the correct font. Add it to your question in a link *and* as a snippet of code, and you might just get an answer!

Comment: Thanks to everyone for responding with a possible solution and/or how to keep this question active.  CSS added (thought the link with an element inspection would suffice, my bad).  Also, I checked the link suggested and it did me no good.  I'll now try each of your suggestions.  Thanks again, all!

Comment: JimmyRare, unfortunately I had the same problem after trying your suggestion.

MisterManSam, I'm still working it out but I think you're on the right track.  I switched the font to Helvetica and the problem was gone.  So I need to figure out how to get my custom font to play nicely with others.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue this morning, you need to define a height as well, that solved the problem for me, it looked great in Chrome but without height it looked squished in Firefox. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried setting the height of the button but to no avail... :(

Comment: hmm try setting a width too? also the line-height could be the issue it can act different in each browser, you could try using padding-top/margin-top instead